# Writing G-code: Audible Alert at end of print

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code

Often, the pre-generated G-code is enough for start and end. However, sometimes we want to have something different. In this case: how to generate an audible alert of something like 4 bleeps at the end of the print, after putting the printer into the end position and when the bed has reached a "safe" 30 °C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's put the parts one by one:

- Wait for bed temperature being at 30 °C: `M190 R30`
- Play Bleep for 1/5th of a second: `M300 S440 P200`
- Wait for 1/5th of a second: `G4 P200`

That gives:

```
M190 R30
M140 S0
M300 S440 P200
G4 P200
M300 S440 P200
G4 P200
M300 S440 P200
G4 P200
M300 S440 P200
G4 P200
```

Just for 0scar:

```
M300 S1396.91 P400 ;f7
G4 P400
M300 S1661.22 P600 ;as7
M300 S1396.91 P400 ;f7
M300 S1396.91 P200 ;f7
M300 S1864.66 P400 ;b7
M300 S1244.51 P400 ;es7
M300 S1396.91 P400 ;f7
G4 P400
M300 S2093.00 P400 ;c8
M300 S1396.91 P400 ;f7
M300 S1396.91 P200 ;f7
M300 S2217.46 P400 ;des8
M300 S2093.00 P400 ;c8
M300 S1661.22 P400 ;as7
M300 S1396.91 P400 ;f7
M300 S2093.00 P400 ;c8
M300 S2793.83 P400 ;f8
M300 S1244.51 P400 ;es7
M300 S1244.51 P200 ;es7
M300 S1046.50 P400 ;c7
M300 S1567.98 P400 ;g7
M300 S1396.91 P1600 ;f7
```

Comment: Cool, I'll implement it as soon as you post how to play [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qx2gvHjNhQ0)! ;)

Comment: @0scar There you go. Beverly Hills cop.

Comment: Lol! I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Trish's version is good but wait for bed temperature being at 30 °C (`M190 R30`) before setting the temperature to 0 °C (`M140 S0`)

So this is my version:

```
G91 ;relative positioning
G1 E-1 F300  ;retract the filament a bit before lifting the nozzle, to release some of the pressure
G1 Z+0.5 E-5 X-20 Y-20 F9000 ;move Z up a bit and retract filament even more
G28 X0 Y0 ;move X/Y to min endstops, so the head is out of the way
G1 Y150 F5000 ;move completed part out
M84 ;steppers off
G90 ;absolute positioning
M190 R30 ;waits until cooling to 30 °C
M300 S300 P1000 ;beep
M300 S300 P1000 ;beep
M300 S300 P1000 ;beep
M300 S300 P1000 ;beep
M104 S0 ;extruder heater off
M140 S0 ;heated bed heater off
```

Comment: S perimeter is "this or more" - 60 is more than 30, so triggers S.

Comment: ups yeah my bad..I was talking about the M190 R30 gcode but - hey - you used the "R" right so my fault..I'm gonna edit my answer

Comment: Yur order of commands in the revamped... You do realize that you set the bed off (M140 S0) and then demand the printer to target 30°C after that and not turn off the bed again?