# Would it be possible to use an Arduino Uno to interface with my Ender 3 pro so I can program it to beep when done?

Tags: creality-ender-3, arduino

I had an idea to make a program for my Arduino Uno that beeps whenever a print is done, but I can't find anything about interfacing it with the printer as all Google gives me is stuff about making a 3D printer from an Arduino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could. But, as an alternative to the Arduino Uno, it might be far easier to send a beep by G-code [`M300`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M300:_Play_beep_sound) (or [here for Marlin firmware](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M300.html)), this will bypass the need for an Arduino Uno entirely. You can even play the soundtrack/theme of Beverly Hills cop [from this previous answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/11057/5740).

You can add the (set of) G-code(s) to the "end G-code" in your slicer.

Comment: I can't find a way to add a custom script at the end in cura

Comment: In Cura, go to your printer configuration and change machine settings, add code in the end G-code script.