# How can a speaker or active buzzer be connected to the Arduino 2560/RAMPS 1.4 boards to provide alerts in response to M300 commands in the g-code

Tags: prusa-i3, g-code, ramps-1.4, arduino-mega-2650

My Prusa i3 does not appear to have any sound device incorporated.  I've read "[Writing G-Code: Audible Alert at end of print](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11056/writing-g-code-audible-alert-at-end-of-print)" and it seems everything needed to implement audible alerts is built into the G-code syntax and firmware but my rig appears to be lacking the necessary noise maker.

Comment: At least on my Ender 3 V2, the speaker is on the LCD control board and not on the mainboard itself.

Comment: There is no LCD unit on my printer, nor an SD card reader. It's directly connected to a PC.

Answer (score 3):

I just looked in the Marlin FW `pins_RAMPS.h` where the pin assignments are located:

```
      #define BEEPER_PIN        37
```

Please check for yourself. I assume you run Marlin, but my version is old and may not be correct.

As you mentioned there is no LCD on your printer so most likely this pin is free, just need to find it.

Also, just a warning, use a proper buzzer or beeper module with the onboard transistor. Do not connect a buzzer directly to the signal pin as the current draw can kill your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Possible is this an idea found at the octoprint web site?

https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/pwmbuzzer/

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please [edit] your answer to explain why it is right. Additionally, we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. [*link only*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/) answers are frowned upon (as links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)) & will be rendered useless if the linked-to content disappears. If you add more context and detail from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.3DP. Unfortunately, our answer is a bit too brief. As already stated, please [edit] and expand your answer, otherwise it will probably be deleted, or converted into a comment. Many thanks.